# Drawing a path in android progressively

Tags: android-canvas, android-view, objectanimator

I have a requirement something like this , I want to drawpath in android in a canvas and for that I have developed a code. This is the view class.

```
public class MyView extends View {
public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public MyView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }


    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        Paint paint = new Paint();

        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);

        paint.setStrokeWidth(3);

        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

        Path path = new Path();

         path.moveTo(100, 100);
         path.lineTo(200, 200);
         path.lineTo(200, 500);
         path.lineTo(400, 500);
         path.lineTo(400, 200);
         path.lineTo(600, 200);
         canvas.drawPath(path, paint);

    }

}
```

This works pretty well and I get the drawpath as I want.
Now there is a small tweak, I want the drawpath to appear gradually in a progressive way ***(say for example the effect a rolling ball will have if it draws a line while rolling left to right, its gradual and slow , but not pausing and drawing)***.

I tried implementing a Timertask to invalidate the view and draw a fresh view, but that simply pauses and draw, not something I want.

I guess, I have to either add an ObjectAnimator or a ValueAnimator to my code.
But I am not sure how to achieve that.
Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I somehow figured it out how to achieve it. I, however could not directly draw a canvas line with animation though but found out a work around and that actually worked for me. I used a horizontal progress bar instead with a negligible height which will look like a line and then added an Object Animator which will gradually fill the line based on the time i set.
    I shall share the code for everyone .

```
In my xml file, I used this, 

<ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/custom_progress"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:max="100"
        android:progress="0"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
         />

And in my Java file , I used this code

    pbr = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);

    animation = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(pbr, "progress", 100);
    animation.setDuration(2000); 
    animation.start();
```

SO in a way, it gives me an effect like the line is drawing progressively. You can try this out and check